# Exporting numpy array as csv imported to Tensorflow.js has no shape

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, tensorflow.js

I need to export numpy arrays from Python to Javascript for use in Tensorflow.js.
I had a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tensorflow-js-tf-data-csv-function/) and tried to do something similar but my imported tensor has no shape, it's not loaded properly.

Export from Python using Pandas dataframe looked like this (simplified):

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
A_df = pd.DataFrame(A)
A_df.to_csv('tmp.csv')
```

The `tmp.csv` looks like this:

```
,0,1,2
0,1,2,3
1,4,5,6
2,7,8,9
3,10,11,12
```

In Javascript it's loaded from url like this, when I test it on my local server:

```
const url = 'https://127.0.0.1/[localurlpath...]/tmp.csv'

const cols = ["", "0", "1", "2"]
let csvConfig = {
  hasHeader: true,
  columnNames: cols
}

const A = tf.data.csv(url, csvConfig)
console.log(A.shape)
```

Console log says: "undefined"

I have tried:

```
delimiter: '\n',
delimWhitespace: true
```

But to no avail.
I also tried other column names to avoid the empty position.
I get no errors in the Javascript console.

Comment: You can tell the pandas csv writer to omit row and column headings.

Comment: Yes, I should look into that. However I tried to remove those manually but that didn't help. There's still no Tensor properly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Since the numpy arrays in question aren't that big,  aprox. 1000x50 at most, I ended upp using this method instead. CSV seemed overly complicated in the situation. Simplified example:

Export from Python:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
with open('mtrx.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(np.array(A).tolist()))
```

Import in Javascript:

```
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1/[...local filepath...]/mtrx.json'
const res = await fetch(url)
const mtrx = await JSON.parse(await res.text())
```

It turns out the imported mtrx object can be used in the `tf.matMul`calculation I need to perform without any further conversion. I thought it needed to be converted to a `tf.tensor`. It was simpler than I thought. I still don't understand what's wrong with my first method but I'll save that for a rainy day.